# SPARK DataFrame: How to efficiently split dataframe for each group based on same column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a DataFrame generated as follows:

```
df.groupBy($"Hour", $"Category")
  .agg(sum($"value").alias("TotalValue"))
  .sort($"Hour".asc,$"TotalValue".desc))
```

The results look like:

```
+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   0|   cat26|      30.9|
|   0|   cat13|      22.1|
|   0|   cat95|      19.6|
|   0|  cat105|       1.3|
|   1|   cat67|      28.5|
|   1|    cat4|      26.8|
|   1|   cat13|      12.6|
|   1|   cat23|       5.3|
|   2|   cat56|      39.6|
|   2|   cat40|      29.7|
|   2|  cat187|      27.9|
|   2|   cat68|       9.8|
|   3|    cat8|      35.6|
| ...|    ....|      ....|
+----+--------+----------+
```

I would like to make new dataframes based on every unique value of `col("Hour")` , i.e.

- for the group of Hour==0
- for the group of Hour==1
- for the group of Hour==2
  and so on...

So the desired output would be:

```
df0 as:

+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   0|   cat26|      30.9|
|   0|   cat13|      22.1|
|   0|   cat95|      19.6|
|   0|  cat105|       1.3|
+----+--------+----------+

df1 as:
+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   1|   cat67|      28.5|
|   1|    cat4|      26.8|
|   1|   cat13|      12.6|
|   1|   cat23|       5.3|
+----+--------+----------+
```

and similarly,

```
df2 as:

+----+--------+----------+
|Hour|Category|TotalValue|
+----+--------+----------+
|   2|   cat56|      39.6|
|   2|   cat40|      29.7|
|   2|  cat187|      27.9|
|   2|   cat68|       9.8|
+----+--------+----------+
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

***EDIT 1:***

What I have tried:

```
df.foreach(
  row => splitHour(row)
  )

def splitHour(row: Row) ={
    val Hour=row.getAs[Long]("Hour")

    val HourDF= sparkSession.createDataFrame(List((s"$Hour",1)))

    val hdf=HourDF.withColumnRenamed("_1","Hour_unique").drop("_2")

    val mydf: DataFrame =df.join(hdf,df("Hour")===hdf("Hour_unique"))

    mydf.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(s"/home/dev/shaishave/etc/myparquet/$Hour/")
  }
```

PROBLEM WITH THIS STRATEGY:

It took 8 hours when it was run on a dataframe `df` which had over 1 million rows and spark job was given around 10 GB RAM on single node. So, `join` is turning out to be highly in-efficient.

Caveat: I have to write each dataframe `mydf` as parquet which has nested schema that is required to be maintained (not flattened).

Comment: Could you do `df.write.partitionBy("hour").saveAsTable("myparquet")` to do this?

Comment: @DennyLee
Thanks, this worked 60 times faster than my strategy!
But it saves the resultant file with names like `hour=0`, `hour=1`,etc and I want files to be saved as `0`,`1`,etc.
Could you please give your insights on how to achieve this?

Comment: You may be able to use hiveContext with the configuration with `hive.dynamic.partitioning.custom.pattern` but one of the advantages of keeping it as `hour=0`, `hour=1`, etc. is that when you're running `spark.read.parquet(...)` it will automatically understand the underlying dynamic partitions.    Another potential approach would be to rename the folders afterwards (i.e. use `mv` command) but you would still run into the same issue that `read.parquet` will not automatically understand the dynamic partitions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As noted in my comments, one potentially easy approach to this problem would be to use:

```
df.write.partitionBy("hour").saveAsTable("myparquet")
```

As noted, the folder structure would be `myparquet/hour=1`, `myparquet/hour=2`, ..., `myparquet/hour=24` as opposed to `myparquet/1`, `myparquet/2`, ..., `myparquet/24`.

To change the folder structure, you could

1. Potentially use the Hive configuration setting `hcat.dynamic.partitioning.custom.pattern` within an explicit HiveContext; more information at [HCatalog DynamicPartitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+DynamicPartitions).
2. Another approach would be to change the file system directly after you have executed the `df.write.partitionBy.saveAsTable(...)` command with something like `for f in *; do mv $f ${f/${f:0:5}/} ; done` which would remove the `Hour=` text from the folder name.

It is important to note that by changing the naming pattern for the folders, when you are running `spark.read.parquet(...)` in that folder, Spark will not automatically understand the dynamic partitions since its missing the partitionKey (i.e. `Hour`) information.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

`df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("hour").parquet("address/to/parquet/location")`

This is similar to the first answer except using [`parquet`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#parquet(path:String):Unit) and using `mode("overwrite")`.

Answer (score -1):

```
//If you want to divide a dataset into n number of equal datasetssets
double[] arraySplit = {1,1,1...,n}; //you can also divide into ratio if you change the numbers.

List<Dataset<String>> datasetList = dataset.randomSplitAsList(arraySplit,1);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include an explanation of the code in your answer. This will make your solution more useful to others, and make it more likely for the post to be upvoted :)