# HDFS TSV to named file

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a set of TSV files on HDFS structured like this:

```
g1  a
g1  b
g1  c
g2  a
g2  x
g2  y
g3  b
g3  d
...
```

I'd like to convert these files into files called `hdfs:///tmp/g1.tsv`, `hdfs:///tmp/g2.tsv`, and `hdfs:///tmp/g3.tsv` such that...

`g1.tsv` looks like:

```
a
b
c
```

`g2.tsv` looks like:

```
a
x
```

`g3.tsv` looks like:

```
b
d
```

etc.

These files are large, and I'd like to do the renaming as parallel as possible. Is there a simple MapReduce job, Spark Job, or an HDFS file operation for doing this?

Comment: with spark, you can use df.partitionBy('column_one'), then save to hdfs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41663985/spark-dataframe-how-to-efficiently-split-dataframe-for-each-group-based-on-same